# trigger events of a lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cli

I have a lambda function which has multiple published versions. Each published version has a trigger event attached to it, which is a cron expression expressed as a rule in aws Eventbridge.

How to get the list of attached trigger events to the published lambda function using aws cli?

Comment: What do you mean by "trigger events"? json input?

Comment: I have an event bridge rule which invokes my lambda function, that I was referring as trigger event, (i am new to the aws, apologies if I am using the terms incorrectly). But essentially I want to capture the list of triggers (which in the UI are shown under configuration tab under triggers)

Comment: No worries you are good. Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44988086/10692493) help?